# Trouble with simple CMAKE tutorial

Tags: cmake

I just followed the simple CMake tutorial on youtube
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=V1YP7eJHDJE

As you can see through the youtube,
folder directory is

```
CMAKE-GOOD
-build
-CMakeLists.txt
-main.cpp
```

this is CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)

project(MyProject VERSION 1.0.0)

add_executable(cmake-good main.cpp)
```

this is main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::cout << "hello, world! \n";
}
```

it is the only source code that I wrote.
and from this part, this will be covered my errors that I encountered

edit) I also did the `cmake ..` in the build directory
the result was shown in below

```
(base) bmssa@bmssa:~/Desktop/CMake_tutorial/CMAKE-GOOD/build$ cmake ..
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/bmssa/Desktop/CMake_tutorial/CMAKE-GOOD/build
```

when I type `cmake --build .` in `~Desktop/CMake_tutorial_CMAKE_GOOD/build`, it shows an Error with

```
(base) bmssa@bmssa:~/Desktop/CMake_tutorial/CMAKE-GOOD/build$ cmake --build .
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable cmake-good
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/cmake-good.dir/build.make:96: recipe for target 'cmake-good' failed
make[2]: *** [cmake-good] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:82: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmake-good.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmake-good.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:90: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

as I heard cmake --build . is similar to make,
so I tried make and it shows an error like this

```
(base) bmssa@bmssa:~/Desktop/CMake_tutorial/CMAKE-GOOD/build$ make
[ 50%] Linking CXX executable cmake-good
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/cmake-good.dir/build.make:96: recipe for target 'cmake-good' failed
make[2]: *** [cmake-good] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:82: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmake-good.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmake-good.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:90: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

when I type `cmake --version`,

```
cmake version 3.20.0

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
```

Can you please help me how to fix it?
I couldn't do anything because I can't even solve this one simple error in the very easy tutorial.
Please HELP ME PLEASE
Thank you

ps.
Because I don't even know what is an error in CMake, could you tell me what should I type in google to solve this?

recipe for taget?
recipe for target 'all' failed?

I don't know what should I type in google....

edit2) I also did the `cmake -S . -B build/foobar` and `cmake --build build/foobar` and this also shows the similar Error like this

```
(base) bmssa@bmssa:~/Desktop/CMake_tutorial/CMAKE-GOOD$ cmake -S . -B build/foobar
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 7.5.0
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc - skipped
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ - skipped
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/bmssa/Desktop/CMake_tutorial/CMAKE-GOOD/build/foobar
(base) bmssa@bmssa:~/Desktop/CMake_tutorial/CMAKE-GOOD$ cmake --build build/foobar
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmake-good.dir/main.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable cmake-good
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/Scrt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
CMakeFiles/cmake-good.dir/build.make:96: recipe for target 'cmake-good' failed
make[2]: *** [cmake-good] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:82: recipe for target 'CMakeFiles/cmake-good.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmake-good.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:90: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: You did run `cmake ..` in your build directory? What was the output, were there some warnings or errors?

Comment: Either the tutorial is bad, or you didn't follow it correctly. The option `--build` is only used *after* you've generated your project binary tree ([link](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#build-a-project)).

Comment: Maybe you recognized that `make` and `cmake --build` had the same output ... Do you know how the C++ build process works?

Comment: Try following this tutorial instead: https://cliutils.gitlab.io/modern-cmake/

Comment: The error is definitely about absence of `main` function in your source file. It **smells** like content of the file is NOT the one as you show us. Try to invalidate that code, e.g. by putting `###` at the beginning. If building the project will emit "undefined reference" again, then it builds NOT your file.

Comment: yeah i did 'cmake ..' to build the directory. when i did it, it shows

Comment: as @Tsyvarev mentioned, even though I commented whole main.cpp and change add_executable(cmake-good main.cpp) to add_executable(cmake-good), it shows and error with undefined reference to 'main' as well although I commented(#) it not to link that main.cpp. it seems content of the file is weirdly cited. however, I think I did correctly, but I don't know why it shows this error again and again. This is the first time I use CMake in ubuntu 16.04, maybe there is some settings that I should do it as "jpr33" mentioned below. but those code are not work at all again....

Comment: Check that your **source** directory (`CMAKE-GOOD`) doesn't contain a file `CMakeCache.txt`. Remove the file if it exists. Recreate (delete and create) build directory and configure the project again. Instead of `cmake ..` you could use `cmake /absolute/path/to/CMAKE-GOOD` for being sure, that exactly your project is configured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my guess to your problem. CMake is unable to find a working toolchain (Compiler, linker, etc.)

Try helping it out by specifying the environment variables CC and CXX.

- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CXX.html
- https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CC.html

```
export CC = /foobar/...../gcc
export CXX = /foobar/...../g++
```

For future reference here is how CMake finds compilers (according to a CMake dev)

1. [CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE.html#variable:CMAKE_TOOLCHAIN_FILE) (if provided)
2. [CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_LANG_COMPILER.html) (if provided)
3. The environment variables [CC](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CC.html?highlight=cc#envvar:CC) or [CXX](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CXX.html?highlight=cxx) (if provided)
4. Then it searches the path environment variable to see if it can find anything.

I guess in your situation none of the above worked. So setting CC and CXX fixed it.